# Pandas Bar Graph not showing accurate distribution

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization, data-analysis

I have a dataset for monthly sales data that I want to determine the best month for sales using bar graph.

The months was indicated using month number on the csv and I have successfully convert the numbers to month name. I applied groupby function to determine the best sales month and found it to be Dec.

The problem are this -

1. After plotting bar of month vs sales value. I found out that the x-axis that was meant to show me the months indicated month in figure (i,e 1-12 month) instead of month name that I have previously converted it to (Jan - Dec)
2. The groupby function indicated Dec to be the highest sales month. But, on the bar graph it was showing Month 3 (i.e march)

Any help will be greatly appreciated

I converted the month number in the csv file to month name to ease visualization of audience using the below code -

`#convert month number to month name`

`all_months_data["Month"]=all_months_data['Month'].apply(lambda x:calendar.month_abbr[x])`

`all_months_data.head()`

Which gave the result as attached.[result after converting month number to name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke1x1.png)

I applied groupby function to see the best month sales to find

`all_sales_month.groupby ('Month').sum()`

[result after groupby function to show highest month sales figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qebM.png)

However, after plotting the bar graph using the following code -

`Month = range(1,13) #for x axis`

`results = all_sales_month.groupby('Month').sum()`

`plt.bar(Month, results['Sales'])`

`plt.xticks(Month)`

`labels, location = plt.yticks()`

`plt.yticks(labels, (labels/1000000).astype(int)) #scaling in million USD`

`plt.ylabel('Sales in million USD')`

`plt.xlabel('Month')`

`plt.show()`

to indicate this visualization, two problems came up -

1. The x axis indicating month was showing the month in numbers instead of Month Name
2. The graph was showing month 3 to be the highest sales month instead of December

[final bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeP7R.png)

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `plt.bar(Month, results['Sales'])` is not a good idea as it ignores the index.  `plt.bar(results['Sales'].index, results['Sales'])` or `results['Sales'].plot.bar()` would be more faithful.  Or  `(results['Sales'] / 1000000).plot.bar()` so you don't need to manipulate the y-axis.

Comment: @JohanC I am deeply grateful. I did as per you mentioned and got a big smile on my face as a result of what I got after running the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your x-axis follows month from 1-12, but the months index in your dataframe does not follow the same order. Which is why the "3rd" month shows the highest sales but it actually corresponds to the month of December.

If you want your x-axis to show the month instead of the month number itself, groupby the month value like this:

```
# extract the month number 
all_months_data['month_no'] = all_months_data['Order Date'].dt.month

# convert the month number to month 
all_months_data['month'] = df['month_no'].apply(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x])

# group by and sort 
all_sales_month = all_months_data.groupby(['month_no', 'month'], as_index=False)['sales'].sum().sort_values(by='month_no')

# Plot your bar graph 
plt.bar(x=all_sales_month['month'], height=all_sales_month['sales'])
```

you can customize your plot after this.

Comment: Many thanks @P. Shroff. However, when I tried the following as u mentioned -                       
 # extract the month number 
all_months_data['month_no'] = all_months_data['Order Date'].dt.month.                                       I received an error saying - AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: Got it. That just means the Order date column is not a DateTime. My guess is it's a string object. 

Just change that line to this: all_months_data['month_no'] = pd.to_datetime(all_months_data['Order Date']).dt.month 

And this should work.